# Saving array to variable name Octave

Tags: save, filenames, octave

I have a loop that each time has new data in an array. I would like to save that array in a .mat file after each insertion of the loop and I want the name of the file to change with the loop value. Say I go through my loop 5 times, I want to have 5 files
array_1.mat
array_2.mat
array_3.mat
array_4.mat
array_5.mat

To test my idea I wrote:

```
for A=1:10;
filename = sprintf('array_%d.mat', A)
save('-mat', filename, 'A');
endfor
```

after running this code in octave, I do get 5 files with the correct names but they don't seem to be .mat file, I can't load them again into octave. I have tried a lot of other small syntax changes and nothing seems to work. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong and/or give my a test example that changes the name of a.mat file with the loop variable.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That works for me so I'm guessing your problem is on the load command. How are you loading the files? You should `load array_5.mat`

Comment: hmmm... It does seem like it should work. When I try load array_5.mat I just get the error: load: unable to find file array_5.mat but I can clearly see that the file is in the current directory. Though when I try to directly open the file by clicking on it, it says "There was a problem opening the file". I am running Ubuntu and Octave version 3.2.4. Is that what you are running?

Comment: @Elena try cd up and down one directory level. I think there was a bug in old versions about that (and you are using a quite old version). I'm using Octave 3.6.2 on Debian. You can build it from source (it's actually not that hard on Ubuntu, see http://wiki.octave.org/Debian ) or you can use one of the unofficial binaries http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_GNU/Linux#Unofficial_binaries )